# $geoWithing in $lookup of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i am looking for query to make a $geoWithin in a lookup of an other collection.

what i actually have is:

```
db.getCollection('polygons').aggregate([{ 
    $lookup: {
        from: "coll1",
        let: { geometry_poly: "$geometry" },
        pipeline: [
            { $match: { "location": { $geoWithin: { $geometry: "$$geometry_poly" } } } },
            { $project: { name: "$hashtag" } }
        ],
        as: "PolyAvg"
    }
}])
```

coll1:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e90bf7b49ebb0e6b459a00f"),
    "hashtag" : "stayhome",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-04-10T18:48:25.876Z"),
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            14.421425, 
            40.26084
        ]
    },
}
```

polygons:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e95d56e49ebb0e6b45a34c4"),
    "type" : "Feature",
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            [ 
                [ ... , ... ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

when i execute this it always says that the $$geometry_poly is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently [Geospatial Query Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-geospatial/) do not accept [expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions).

Comment: is there an other way to solve this with 1 query or do i have to select the polygons first and query the other collection with a second query?

Comment: @HaraldWiesinger Exactly. You need to do 1 query to retrieve `polygons` and then call `coll1` collection for each `polygon` item

Comment: i do this with restheart, really no chance to reduce this to one http call? :D

Comment: Try this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/server-side-javascript/